# What does "end of file" mean in C?

Tags: c, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
}
```

In the above code, which character will break the loop?
I am new to C, please help me.
Also, what is it meant by this error:
`codec5.c:8:2: warning: no newline at end of file`

Comment: Please do not write all in caps.. IT MEANS SHOUTING!

Comment: Is it just me?! Your caps-lock jammed right?

Comment: edited your post to stop my eyes from bleeding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is solved by putting a newline at the end of the file (put the cursor behind the `}` and press enter).

I think the loop is broken with Ctrl+Z, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The loop is broken when it reaches the end of the file, not a special character. Some legacy implementations implemented end-of-file (for text files) by having a special character mark the end, rather than storing the exact length of the file in the filesystem bookkeeping information, but those days are long past.

Comment: On Windows, control-Z probably is used to mark EOF in a text file, or typed at the command window; in a binary file, EOF is reached when there are no more unread characters.  On Unix, there is no EOF character in a file - EOF is reached when there are no more characters in the file.  The character typed at a terminal to indicate EOF is configurable with the `stty` command; the default is usually control-D these days.

Comment: Well, I'm not programming in C++ so much nowadays, but I interpreted `getchar` as getting input from stdin. So I thought OP was asking for a way to end the loop using the keyboard, which I remembered to be either Ctrl+C (break) or Ctrl+Z (eof) (the latter being used to indicate EOF on DOS indeed).

Comment: I know it says `end of file` in the question, but that's because there are actually two totally unrelated questions. :-p

Comment: Looked it up: It is indeed Ctrl+Z in Windows. Ctrl+D in Linux: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread79432.html

Answer (score 1):

The warning just means that you need to have a new line at the end of your source code.  Put your cursor at the last `}` in your file at the end of `main()` and press enter.

You need to check for a specific character to end the program if you are not loading from a file.  If you pipe (`|`) (`<` in Windows) a file into your program, then the program should end.  If your program is named `test.exe` and your input file is `foo.txt`, try running `test.exe < foo.txt` (make sure they are in the same directory).

Answer (score 0):

It is a special constant defined in `stdio.h` which means *the end of the file*.

> codec5.c:8:2: warning: no newline at end of file

Sounds like you don't have a `\n` at the end of your file :)